# get farthest vertice on a specified direction of a 3D model - Unity

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, vertices

I need to get the position of the farthest vertice fo a model given the direction vector and the model.

Eg

obj has the following vertices:

`vertice a = (0,0,1)`
`vertice b = (0,1,0)`
`vertice c = (1,0,0)`
`vertice d = (0,0,0)`

so

`GetPoint(obj, Vector3.up);`

will return vertice b

thanks in advance

Comment: You need a distance notion to compute the farthest point not just a direction. If you have a direction + a reference point you can construct a line along which you can search the farthest point from the reference or construct a plane and you only search in one side of the plane unless your direction is used to define a special metric or measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code will give the farthest point but only for meshes with no submeshes you can change the code a little to do it for submeshes..

```
Vector3 GetFarPoint (Transform obj, Vector3 direction) {

        Vector3[] vertices;
        Vector3 farthestPoint;
        float farDistance;

        vertices = obj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;
        farDistance=0f;

        foreach(Vector3 vert in vertices)
        {
            float temp = Vector3.Dot(direction,vert);
            if(temp>farDistance)
            {
                farDistance = temp;
                farthestPoint = vert;
            }
        }
        return farthestPoint;
    }
```